# The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because: Unsuported config for service: 'pihole'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file and getting this error:

```
The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because: Unsuported config for service: 'pihole'
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
 services:
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    ports:
      - "53:53/tcp"
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "67:67/udp"
      - "80:80/tcp"
      - "443:443/tcp"
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Zurich'
      WEBPASSWORD: 'mySuperSecrectPW'
    volumes:
       - './etc-pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
       - './etc-dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 1.1.1.1
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
```

I already stripped every argument that is not absolutely necessary, but still getting the same error. Sorry if that is a stupid question to ask, but I am new to the whole docker topic and still learning.

Comment: Can you share more details? Do you call any command that triggers this message?

Comment: docker-compose up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Compose files that do not declare a version are considered “version 1”. In those files, all the services are declared at the root of the document.

See [Compose file versions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/).

Try adding `version: '3.7'` or whatever version you like at the top level.